# Finding symbols in files using Perl

Tags: perl

I am new to Perl and trying to learn it. I have two files, 'file1' and 'file2', I need to find which symbols in 'file1' are not in 'file2' for companyA and departments B and C.

File1

```
GTY
TTY 
UJK
TRE
```

File2

```
departmentA_companyA.try=675 UJK 88 KKR
departmentA_companyB.try=878 UJK 37 TAR
departmentA_companyC.try=764 UJK 92 PAM
departmentB_companyA.try=675 UJK 88 KKR
departmentB_companyB.try=878 UJK 37 TAR
departmentB_companyC.try=764 UJK 92 PAM
departmentC_companyA.try=675 UJK 88 KKR
departmentC_companyB.try=878 UJK 37 TAR
departmentC_companyC.try=764 UJK 92 PAM
```

Comment: I am still looking where to start from.. can you please give me direction

Comment: Without knowing anything about your previous knowledge, and without any indication that you have done some work yourself, the best I can do is suggest that you google "how to ask questions the smart way"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a list of all the symbols in file1
2. Go through file2. If the criteria matches, delete the symbol from the list.

In this case, I'd suggest you use the keys of a hash to store this list (`$symbols{$symbol} = 1;`). This is because it's easy and cheap to delete from a hash (`delete $symbols{$symbol};`).

Spoiler:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

my %symbols;
{
   open(my $fh, '<', 'file1')
      or die("Can't open file1: $!\n");

   while (<$fh>) {
      chomp;
      ++$symbols{$_};
   }
}

{
   open(my $fh, '<', 'file2')
      or die("Can't open file2: $!\n");

   while (<$fh>) {
      chomp;
      my ($key, $val) = split /=/;
      my ($dept, $co) = split /[_\.]/, $key;
      if ($co eq 'companyA' || $dept eq 'departmentB' || 'departmentC') {
         my @symbols = split ' ', $val;
         delete @symbols{@symbols};
      }
   }
}

say for keys %symbols;
```

Comment: @Sam, it's actually very similar to David Nehme's solution. It's more accurate at finding companies and departments. (e.g. Trying to find the "IT" deptartment won't accidentally match the "BUY IT!" company.) It's simpler since I don't maintain a count of how many times things are found. It's longer because I separated concerns into separate blocks.

Comment: @Sam - if this answer meets your needs, please hit the checkmark next to it to formally accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a hash to count the number of times each symbol appears in the file, then print the ones that have a count of 0.

```
use strict;

open SYMS, $ARGV[0] || die;
open INFILE, $ARGV[1] || die;

my %symbols;

while (<SYMS>) {
    chomp;
    $symbols{$_} = 0;
}

while (<INFILE>) {
    my @F=split;
    next unless $F[0] =~ /companyA/;
    next unless $F[0] =~ /department[BC]/;
    ++$symbols{$F[1]} if (defined $symbols{$F[1]});
    ++$symbols{$F[3]} if (defined $symbols{$F[3]});
}

for my $symbol (keys %symbols) {
    print "$symbol\n" if $symbols{$symbol} == 0;
}
```